# Determine if SqlTransaction wrote data or was read only

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm going to start off by saying I am pretty sure this is not possible. Googling has not turned up anyone asking this question, so I am pessimistically hopeful.

I am using a SqlTransaction to connect to a database, and allowing several consumers to use this transaction before I close it. Is it possible to determine whether or not the transaction was only used to read data or to read/write data, even when stored procedures may have been used? Does some property or SQL method (other than performing some unholy diff) exist that can check this?

Comment: I also doubt that this can be done, but it's an interesting question. +1

Comment: What's the intent of this?

Comment: Several, actually. The first is error logging, perf analysis is another. But really it's a general question, it would have a lot of use cases if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) has a column `writes`. You can query it like this:

```
SELECT writes FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

That will impose some overhead, though. I think that DMV is `O(N)` in the number of sessions running. The system will slow down the more sessions there are. Eventually it becomes a case of negative scaling.

Note, that this is a per-session value. If you have multiple transactions per session (per opening of a `SqlConnection` object) the writes will be tracked cumulatively. You'd need to account for that, or use the idea in the other answer.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between this and Jiggs answer?

Comment: @Tyrsius I'm not sure whether the two different techniques would detect different kinds of writes, or whether they are identical. In case they produce identical outcomes, which I think is likely, choose the one that is simpler and faster. That's probably the session write column.

Comment: If you test this with my initial transaction scenario, writes=0 after inserting a row into my test table.

Comment: @JiggsJedi I just executed the first SQL block from your answer, then ran my statement. It showed writes. Did I miss something?

Comment: Not sure, maybe I'm missing something... did you commit the tran?  i am getting 0 writes on an open tran... very odd.

Comment: I did not commit it. But after committing it, the writes counter was still > 0. This is a problem. Will edit the answer. Your answer should be accepted because the OP asked for per-tran writes and I provided per-session writes.

Comment: I'm getting 0 writes with open and committed transactions... very strange.  I love the simplicity of your answer, but I cannot reproduce results.

Comment: I'm on 2012 R2 CU 9. Tested both in tempdb and user database.

Comment: Was just trying to help, no need to patronize me.

Comment: Man, it is really hard to convey emotions with text. I meant that in a friendly way.

Comment: My mistake then.  +1 for you too.  Your answer is far cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sys.dm_ views to check Transaction status.

When a transaction is opened, but no work is done (select only), it doesn't register, but if you do any work, the transaction log size is increased.

Try this first... note your SPID.

```
USE tempdb
begin tran
create table dave (id int)
insert into dave (id) select 1
-- rollback tran
```

Leave the transaction open, then look at it with this (replace your spid):

```
select database_transaction_log_bytes_used, *
from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions dt 
inner join sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at on (at.transaction_id = dt.transaction_id)   
inner join sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st on (st.transaction_id = dt.transaction_id) 
where (dt.database_id = DB_ID('tempdb')) and (st.is_user_transaction=1) 
and session_id=83
```

Then rollback the original.

Then try this:

```
USE tempdb
begin tran
select getdate()
-- rollback tran
```

And run the above on the sys.dm_ views...

The view is blank until there is something logged in the transaction.  Selects do not get logged.

Don't forget to roll it all back.

So you could write a proc/view that you could query before closing your transaction, assuming you know the spid (easy enough to query for with `SELECT @@SPID`) that would return you the log size of the active session.

Answer (score 0):

mmm, **`This is only an idea`**. I am thinking about something like.. creating a table in your database, calling `CountRead`, and another table `CountWrite`, and then, modify your querys to write in read table if the query is a SELECT and in the write table if the query is an INSERT or something. Then, when you want to check if only read or write, you only need to read this tables (if they already have data, you can or remove all the data when your application starts, or check the count in the beginning).

Then with a simple SELECT to this tables, you will be able to check if only read querys have been used, or only write querys, or both, and how many times.

As I said, is only an idea. ;) I hope this helps, or at least give you some idea about how to do it

Comment: This solution could work, but it relies on coordination from all consumers. If some naughty stored procedures forget to update, then it will falsely report a read-only action.

Comment: As I said, was only an idea to try to help :) But you are right @Tyrsius